# What's the significance of weird phrases?

Tags: pokemon, pokemon-detective-pikachu

In *Pokémon: Detective Pikachu* (2019), when Tim and his Pokémon partner Pikachu are about to meet Mime, there is a following discussion:

> Tim: We're not cops.
>
> Pikachu: **Grow some berries**. You're bigger, tougher-looking.

Which sounds close to **Grow some balls**.

---

In another scene, Pikachu speaks to Tim near Magikarp:

> Pikachu: Magikarp can evolve into Gyarados. All it needs is a little kick. **Water in the hole!** In my head, I saw that differently.

Which sounds close to **Fire in the hole**.

---

What's the significance of these weird phrases?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for an English stackexchange. They're puns of sorts.

Comment: Grow some berries is a kid-friendly version of "*grow a pair of balls*" (e.g. show some machismo)

Comment: @Theik The question could probably fit there but it's a better fit for SFF, especially considering the puns are backed with Pokemon references not just basic puns.

Comment: "Water in the hole" is the aquatic version of *"fire in the hole"*, shouted before throwing a grenade

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Pokémon games (and anime), Pokémon use berries to cure status effects and restore HP. This is just a little nod towards it and a more kid-friendly way of saying it.

"Water in the hole" is probably just a little reference to the fact that Magikarp is a water Pokémon.

Comment: This is it, exactly.  They're family-friendly conversions of common phrases that incorporate parts of the pokemon mythos.